# Solr Bridge on CE, exclude product descriptions

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, solr, search-terms

Using Solr bridge extension on 1.8.1.

I need to *exclude* product descriptions from being used to generate search results, as it contains text that can confuse the search results.

For example, if the description says "This lamp is designed to stand on a table." then when the phrase "table" is searched for, the lamp appears in the search results, which is not desired behavior in this case.

How would I do this? Can it be done by editing the configuration of the solr installation itself or will it need to be done within the Magento extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the documentation you would remove the search options on the description attribute within magento, and reindex to exclude product descriptions.

- http://www.solrbridge.com/documents/magento-solr-bridge-installation.html#fieldssettings